# Add OneNote page to active Microsoft Teams meeting

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-teams

In Microsoft Teams, I can add a OneNote page to a chat or team, but I'd like to add one to a meeting so that all participants can view/edit. How do I do this?  I would prefer this to a whiteboard as it has more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the link to the OneNote page by right clicking on page and `Copy Link to Page`. And share this link to all the participants.

[image: onenote copy the page]

Then Edit this page on the Online version of OneNote in the web browser. It should allow multiple people to edit/sync at one during the meeting. (I have not tried it personally though).

[image: onenote share notebook]

Also, you need to make sure that **everyone in the meeting have access to the OneNote Notebook** that you are editing.

Hope it helps.